# Nimbus JDK 6u27 applet crashes when running in JRE 7u4

Tags: applet, java, nimbus

We have a web application that extends the Nimbus LaF library with custom painters for various controls. The applet is built against JDK 6u27, and runs as expected against JRE 6.x, however we have run into issues when running it against JRE 7u4.

We extend `AbstractRegionPainter` for our custom Painter classes and attempt to instantiate a `PaintContext`, which causes a "class not found" exception to be thrown.

We realise that Nimbus has been moved into `javax.swing` in Java 7, and that `com.sun.java.swing.plaf.nimbus.AbstractRegionPainter` (which we import) now extends `javax.swing.plaf.nimbus.AbstractRegionPainter`, however it does not appear that Oracle have provided similar redirection for the `PaintContext` inner class.  The applet displays the following in the debug log:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-2" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/java/swing/plaf/nimbus/AbstractRegionPainter$PaintContext
...
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.java.swing.plaf.nimbus.AbstractRegionPainter$PaintContext
at sun.plugin2.applet.Applet2ClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass0(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
```

Since any classes that extend `AbstractRegionPainter` must provide a `PaintContext`, this seems like a backwards compatibility bug in JRE7u4, but if anyone has any ideas about how we can fix/workaround this issue it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I suggest 1) Check the bug database 2) If you find something, it might have a workaround 3) If you don't, raise a report.